# Django view seems to be called twice

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-templates, django-views

I hit a url defined in urls.py as

```
url(r'getplacesnearbytest/$', api.getPlacesNearby, name='getPlacesNearby'),
```

from a jQuery post with post parameters:

```
lat=51.542623&lon=-0.089851
```

Along with a crsf token and an unused parameter (used in the js). In the view method, getPlacesNearby(), I print the post object and the word 'end'.

```
print request.POST
print 'end'
```

The result is below, it seems to be called twice

```
<QueryDict: {u'dest': [u'/smcore/geteventsnearbytest/'], u'lat': [u'51.542623'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'Xc65nWy67mNxvshpmK4yTMdRIm5EaYCK'], u'lon': [u'-0.089851']}>
end
[28/Jan/2014 16:38:23] "POST /smcore/geteventsnearbytest/ HTTP/1.1" 500 12248
<QueryDict: {}>    
end
[28/Jan/2014 16:38:23] "GET /smcore/geteventsnearbytest/ HTTP/1.1" 500 64635
```

Client side code:

```
$('.testApisPost').on('click', function() {

  var dataObj = {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
  }

  $.each($(this).data(), function(i, v) {
    dataObj[i] = v
  });

  $.post($(this).data("dest"), dataObj, function(data){
    console.log(data)
  })
});
```

html:

```
<div class="testApisPost startLink areaBlock" data-dest="{% url 'getPlacesNearby' %}" data-lat="51.542623" data-lon="-0.089851" data-radius="5" data-types="food">
    This gets clicked
</div>
```

At the end of the method I call

```
return HttpResponse(res, content_type="application/json")
```

To send data back. Any ideas as to why the duplication is occurring?

Comment: The duplication is very likely within your Javascript code. Please post your client-side code as well.

Comment: Added the js and html

Comment: Still struggling with this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have found why the view is called twice, there was a js action tied to the startLink class that came from an earlier version of the project.

Thanks to all those that helped

Comment: Could you elaborate? I have the same problem (although I don't use JS - but it's still tied to the HTML/CSS side of things)

Comment: To be honest I have absolutely no idea what any of this does, haven't touched it in over 3 years